# Calling UITextView() takes 5.8 second in keyboard extension with Swift 2?

Tags: ios, swift, migration, swift2

I just updated my XCode form 6.3 to 7.1 and thus also my project from Swift 1.2 to Swift 2.

Everyting seems to work except my app starts some 6 seconds slower then it used to.

I tracked the problem to this class initializer:

```
class TextPreviewAdapter {
    private let themeProvider: ThemeProvider
    private let containerView: UIView
    private let previewText: UITextView
    private let carretView: UIView

    private var carretTextPosition: UITextPosition?

    init(themeProvider: ThemeProvider) {
        self.themeProvider = themeProvider
        containerView = UIView()
        let time = CACurrentMediaTime()
        previewText = UITextView()
        print("TextPreviewAdapter \(CACurrentMediaTime() - time)")
        carretView = UIView()
    }

    //some unimportant code
}
```

The output of the print call is

```
TextPreviewAdapter 5.86848595833144
```

The time is different every time I run the up from XCode.

The app is keyboard extension. This might not be the only performance problem introduced by the migration. The whole app appear slugish, in particual rotation animations are slow, somethimes a fast swipe is not handled... Nothing of that was present before migration.

On output I have some suspicious logs (also not present before migration):

```
2015-10-23 00:39:55.591 ProductName Keyboard[3293:300203] _BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid capability (20)
2015-10-23 00:39:55.592 ProductName Keyboard[3293:300203] _BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid name (15)
2015-10-23 00:39:55.593 ProductName Keyboard[3293:300203] _BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid capability (20)
2015-10-23 00:39:55.593 ProductName Keyboard[3293:300203] _BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid name (15)
2015-10-23 00:45:02.532 ProductName Keyboard[3293:300964] host connection <NSXPCConnection: 0x147e459c0> connection from pid 3292 invalidated
```

Anybody had the same problem? Any ideas on how to solve this issues?

Comment: Maybe this is iOS problem? Since iOS 8, even standard keyboard has gap in the loading...

Comment: @VitaliyGozhenko On iOS 8 the same code runs under `0.1` second (still long for initializing 3 views but fine for me). And I thing standard keyboard is using no `UITextView`. The gap in loading has different reason, this is another issue. And 6 seconds is a *long* time, it really makes the user press home button istead of waiting...

Comment: I'm getting the same error messages while I'm rotating my app. Normal app with UIWebView inside. Takes very long time to rotate and the space around the WebView is partly black for some seconds, before the rotation has finished. Do you have a solution by now?

Comment: @Lupurus No solution I simply removed UITextView from the app (replaced by something else, took a lot of work). Since than the `NSXPCConnection` error disapeared but I still see `invalid capability` errors. They seems to be related to text somehow and they do not show off every time. I do have some rotation issues (jerking when rotating) that was not present in iOS 8 but I do not know whether they are related to `invalid capability/name` errors.

Comment: I found out, that I'm getting the errors only because I have a huge html-file and two different css files for each orientation. I think that there have to be a lot of new calculations at rotating and it seems that this is my problem (the error says: "invalid capability"). I made some tweaks in Javascript so that the recalculations are not done at the rotation animation. This solved the rotation flickering and the errors (but it's not a real solution, because the tweak is to hide the content until the 'recalculation' has finished). Don't know, if this helps you in any way.

Comment: @Lupurus Any information can be a hint. Even the informantion that it might be connected with rotation after all is valuable. Thank you.